# kafka client getting TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED on cluster restart

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using an SSL enabled kafka cluster to connect to consumer and publish messages. Below is the tech stack.

```
spring-kafka : 2.6.6
spring-boot  :  2.4.3
```

> Kafka properties

```
kafka:
 bootstrap-servers: ${BOOTSTRAP-SERVERS-HOST}
 subscription-topic: TEST
 properties:
   security.protocol: SSL
   ssl.truststore.location: ${SUBSCRIPTION_TRUSTSTORE_PATH}
   ssl.truststore.password: ${SUBSCRIPTION_TRUSTSTORE_PWD}
   ssl.keystore.location: ${SUBSCRIPTION_KEYSTORE_PATH}
   ssl.keystore.password: ${SUBSCRIPTION_KEYSTORE_PWD}
```

**Issue:**
Kafka Client application is up connected to the kafka cluster consumer and publishing messages as expected.
Now  we stop the kafka broker/cluster below error is logged.

```
could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

This is fine and expected as broker/cluster is down.

Now We start the broker/cluster and below error start appearing and kafka consumer stops consuming messages from topic however kafka publisher is able to send message to the topic.  [application restart resolves this issue]

*Trying to understand the root cause any help is much appreciated.*

```
2022-01-13 13:34:52.078 [TEST.CONSUMER-GROUP-0-C-1] ERROR--SUBSCRIPTION -  -org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata.checkUnauthorizedTopics - [Consumer clientId=consumer-TEST.CONSUMER-GROUP-1, groupId=TEST.CONSUMER-GROUP] Topic authorization failed for topics [TEST]
2022-01-13 13:34:52.078 [TEST.CONSUMER-GROUP-0-C-1] ERROR- -SUBSCRIPTION -  -org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor.error - Authorization Exception and no authorizationExceptionRetryInterval set
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [TEST]

2022-01-13 13:34:52.081 [TEST.CONSUMER-GROUP-0-C-1] ERROR- IRVS-SUBSCRIPTION -  -org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor.error - Fatal consumer exception; stopping container
2022-01-13 13:34:52.083 [TEST.CONSUMER-GROUP-0-C-1] INFO - IRVS-SUBSCRIPTION -  -org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport.shutdown - Shutting down ExecutorService
```

Comment: The error seems obvious - see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz

Comment: let me check this

Comment: @GaryRussell 
If no authorizationExceptionRetryInterval is set then container stop throwing an Authorization Exception.
Is this a correct behaviour?  It should default to  x seconds, opinion please

Comment: The container does not throw the exception. Authorization exceptions thrown by the consumer are fatal by default and the container stops. If there is a retry interval, the container will sleep for the interval and try again (repeatedly).

Answer (score 0):

Above issue was resolved after adding

> AuthorizationException RetryInterval

Below is an example illustrating this

```
 @Bean
   ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
           ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
           ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
       ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
       factory.setConcurrency(2);
       configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
       // other setters like error handler , retry handler
       // setting Authorization Exception Retry Interval 
       factory.getContainerProperties()
               .setAuthorizationExceptionRetryInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(5l));

       return factory;
   }
```